# Javascript getting value of a textarea without using JQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I know this should be as easy as just doing `myTextArea.value`, but it doesn't seem to work unless I use JQuery on the `id`.

So I create this Javascript object, and on it I assign a property called `assignmentQuestionTextArea`. Here's the full code of me doing that:

```
TextQuestionAssignmentTakingPage.prototype.makeContent = function (question) {
    var questionWrapper = StageAssignmentTakingPage.prototype.makeContent.call(this, question);

    var answerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    answerDiv.setAttribute("id", "assignmentTakingQuestionAnswerWrapper");
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.setAttribute("id", "assignmentTakingTextQuestionTextArea");
    textArea.innerHTML = this.answerSupplied;
    this.assignmentQuestionTextArea = textArea;
    answerDiv.innerHTML = textArea.outerHTML;

    questionWrapper.innerHTML += answerDiv.outerHTML;

    return questionWrapper.outerHTML;
};
```

So there it is. That is called early on. Then when I click on some button later on I call a method of this `TextQuestionAssignmentTakingPage` object called `hasBeenChanged`. In here I attempt to look at the value of `this.assignmentQuestionTextArea` and see if it's different then what I have saved. The saved value is in a property called `answerSupplied`.

```
TextQuestionAssignmentTakingPage.prototype.hasBeenChanged = function () {
    alert($('#assignmentTakingTextQuestionTextArea').val() + " - " + this.assignmentQuestionTextArea.value + " - " + this.assignmentQuestionTextArea.innerHTML);
    if (this.answerSupplied === null) { // just need to check if an answer exists
        var patt = /^\s*$/; // pattern for any number of spaces and nothing else
        var result = patt.test($(this.assignmentQuestionTextArea).val());
        if (result == true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else { // need to look at what the answer was and see if it has changed
        if ($(this.assignmentQuestionTextArea).val() === this.answerSupplied) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is, the first time doing this, `this.assignmentQuestionTextArea.value` always seems to be an empty string. Yes, it does work by doing wrapping the `id` of the `textarea` in a JQuery object and using `.val()`, but I'd really like this to work even if `this.assignmentQuestionTextArea` isn't currently on the screen.

Why won't it give me the most up to date value?

Comment: It could be because the textarea has been dynamically added to the DOM and jQuery doesn't know about it yet...

Comment: His question is about NOT using jQuery.

Comment: Well if I use JQuery like this $('#assignmentTakingTextQuestionTextArea').val() it gives me the value fine. The problem is when I'm just acting on the textarea object saved to the assignmentQuestionTextArea property. I want to get the value from there because I'd like this to work even if the textarea isn't currently on the screen/ in the dom.

Comment: You never set the value of `this.assignmentQuestionTextArea`, you set its `innerHTML`. Try using `(this.assignmentQuestionTextArea).html()`.

Comment: That still does not work. I don't set the value because in the case that answerSupplied is null, there should be no value. The value I'm attempting to get in the call to hasBeenChanged is the value that the user has entered.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a jsfiddle demonstrating this? I have theories, but I can't actually reproduce the issue; `.value` always seems to work for me.

Comment: Well it's kind of baked into a lot of stuff so it will be a bit difficult to get a jsfiddle of it. I can see what I can come up with though.

Comment: One thing that's often a good strategy for debugging stuff like this, is to come up with the smallest case you can to reproduce the problem. Easier to get help, but also just easier to fix yourself, since you're then ONLY testing that specific issue, and don't have to worry about the rest.

Comment: One thing I am noticing right now is this only happens when I create a textarea element. If I create a input with attribute type = text everything works as expected. I really need a textarea though.

Comment: Well I think it has something to do with your setting of the initial value with `.innerHTML` rather than `.value` or `.textContent`. Have you tried using those instead?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, using input still doesn't work. I have tried using value and it does nothing. Here is a js fiddle. For some reason the event listener is not working, but if it were that would test for value. http://jsfiddle.net/JtrE4/1/

Comment: Okay, here's an example that does work, and I still can't reproduce the issue. The reason your test didn't work is that you added an event listener to an actual element object, but then you didn't use that element itself, you took its HTML representation and used that. That made a new element that didn't include the original's event listeners.

Comment: Err, right, here's the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/JtrE4/2/